# Proper Way to Remove Thumbnail Links In Gallery

Tags: gallery

I use the [**`post_gallery` filter**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/43562/10691) in functions.php to replace the core gallery code, with the gallery code I've modified to suit my needs, like this:

```
function aahan_post_gallery($output, $attr) {
    global $post;

    static $instance = 0;
    $instance++;

    // We're trusting author input, so let's at least make sure it looks like a valid orderby statement
    if ( isset( $attr['orderby'] ) ) {
        $attr['orderby'] = sanitize_sql_orderby( $attr['orderby'] );
        if ( !$attr['orderby'] )
            unset( $attr['orderby'] );
    }

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'order'      => 'ASC',
        'orderby'    => 'menu_order ID',
        'id'         => $post->ID,
        'itemtag'    => 'div',
        'icontag'    => '',
        'captiontag' => 'div',
        'columns'    => 3,
        'size'       => 'full',
        'include'    => '',
        'exclude'    => ''
    ), $attr));

    $id = intval($id);
    if ( 'RAND' == $order )
        $orderby = 'none';

    if ( !empty($include) ) {
        $include = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $include );
        $_attachments = get_posts( array('include' => $include, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );

        $attachments = array();
        foreach ( $_attachments as $key => $val ) {
            $attachments[$val->ID] = $_attachments[$key];
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($exclude) ) {
        $exclude = preg_replace( '/[^0-9,]+/', '', $exclude );
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'exclude' => $exclude, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    } else {
        $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => $id, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => $order, 'orderby' => $orderby) );
    }

    if ( empty($attachments) )
        return '';

    if ( is_feed() ) {
        $output = "\n";
        foreach ( $attachments as $att_id => $attachment )
            $output .= wp_get_attachment_link($att_id, $size, true) . "\n";
        return $output;
    }

    $itemtag = tag_escape($itemtag);
    $captiontag = tag_escape($captiontag);
    $columns = intval($columns);
    $itemwidth = $columns > 0 ? floor(100/$columns) : 100;
    $float = is_rtl() ? 'right' : 'left';

    $selector = "gallery-{$instance}";

    $gallery_style = $gallery_div = '';
    if ( apply_filters( 'use_default_gallery_style', true ) )
        $gallery_style = "
        <style type='text/css'>
            #{$selector} {
                margin: auto;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-item {
                float: {$float};
                margin-top: 10px;
                text-align: center;
                width: {$itemwidth}%;
            }
            #{$selector} img {
                border: 2px solid #cfcfcf;
            }
            #{$selector} .gallery-caption {
                margin-left: 0;
            }
        </style>
        <!-- see gallery_shortcode() in wp-includes/media.php -->";
    $size_class = sanitize_html_class( $size );
    $gallery_div = "<div id='myCarousel' class='gallery-carousel slide'><div class='carousel-inner'>";
    $output = apply_filters( 'gallery_style', $gallery_style . "\n\t\t" . $gallery_div );

    $i = 0;
    foreach ( $attachments as $id => $attachment ) {
        $count++;
        $aahan_active = (1 == $count) ? ' active' : '';
        $link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);

        $output .= "<{$itemtag} class='item$aahan_active'>";
        $output .= "$link";
        if ( $captiontag && trim($attachment->post_excerpt) ) {
            $output .= "
               <{$captiontag} class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption'>
               " . wptexturize($attachment->post_excerpt) . "
               </{$captiontag}>";
        }
        $output .= "</{$itemtag}>";
        if ( $columns > 0 && ++$i % $columns == 0 )
            $output .= '<br style="clear: both" />';
    }

    $output .= "
            <br style='clear: both;' />
        </div></div>\n";

    return $output;
}
add_filter("post_gallery", "aahan_post_gallery",10,2);
```

Now, I am pretty sure that this line in the code is responsible for linking gallery thumbnails to their Attachment Page or full-size image:

```
$link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
```

How should I modify the line so that the thumbnails don't link to anything at all? (i.e. no `<a href="">` around thumbnails in gallery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using 2 separate functions to grab the attachment you can use the same function, and then add the URL in separately using `wp_get_attachment_url`, making the logic much clearer, and reducing the amount of work needed:

e.g.

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );

// if it's set to not show the image link
if(isset($attr['link']) && ('none' == $attr['link']) ){
    // then just show the image
    echo $image;
} else {
    // else show the image wrapped in a link
    $link = wp_get_attachment_url($id);
    echo "<a href=\"$link\">$image</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace this line in your filtered gallery code:

```
$link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
```

With this:

```
$link = wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size);
```

Your gallery images are no longer hyperlinked -- i.e. they are linked to neither the attachment page nor the attachment file.

---

### ALTERNATIVES

Replace:

```
$link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
```

[With this](http://web.archive.org/web/20101029232913/http://blog.mattsatorius.com/technology/web-design/wordpress-gallery-shortcode-with-no-image-link/):

```
if(isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link']){ $link = wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false); } elseif (isset($attr['link']) && 'none' == $attr['link']){$link = wp_get_attachment_image($id, $size, false);} else {  $link = wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false); }
```

### OR

Replace:

```
$link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
```

[With this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/23334/10691):

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image( $id, $size, false );
$link = isset($attr['link']) && 'file' == $attr['link'] ? wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, false, false) : wp_get_attachment_link($id, $size, true, false);
$image_output = ( 'none' == $attr['link'] ? $image : $link );
```

Now, the just mentioned two methods allow you to use the `link="none"` parameter when you don't want the thumbnails in a specific gallery to be hyperlinked. (**EDIT:** Take a look at [Tom's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/51623/10691), he's provided some better code.)